# .NET core DbContext dynamic connectionstring

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to set the connectionstring of my DbContext depending on each http request header. Is it possible to do so in .NET Core? I did it in MVC5 but I am not able to implement it in .NET core.

At

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
}
```

I don't know the http header, so where can I do it?

Comment: MVC doesn't have connection strings. It has nothing to do with databases. *EF* does. Have you tried setting the connection string as you did with the previous version of EF? What did you try? Please post the code

Comment: BTW what do you mean dynamic? Do you want to target different databases per request, use different credentials per end user or don't you want to use a configuration file for the connection string? Otherwise, why not just use the connection string stored in the config file?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is: I'm trying to connect to different databases depending on each HTTP request. On the HTTP request header I send the name of the connectionString.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this to use the HTTP request content inside the `DbContext` type instantiation:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddScoped<HttpContext>(p => p.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext);
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();

    var descriptor = new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>),
        DbContextOptionsFactory,
        ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

    var descriptorNonGeneric = new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(DbContextOptions),
        typeof(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>), 
        ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

    services.Replace(descriptor);
    services.Replace(descriptorNonGeneric);

    // ...
}

private DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> DbContextOptionsFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    var httpContext = provider.GetService<HttpContext>();
    // here we have the complete HttpContext
    var myHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["MyHeader"];
    var connectionString = GetConnectionStringFromHeader(myHeader);

    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

    return optionsBuilder.Options;
}
```

Because the `AddDbContext<TDbContext>` extension method of EFCore will already register a `DbContextOptions` as a singleton, we need to overwrite this registration and add our own `DbContextOption` factory method which uses `HttpContext` and is executed with `Scoped` lifetime.

This way we may change options (including the connection string) on every request.

Comment: I will try this. What I am trying to do is to connect to different connectionStrings depending on the HTTP request Header. I send the conenctionstring in the HTTP request header.

Comment: Only works for first load. Not for every http request. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @tunoandsuno Edited the answer. Try with this solution.

Comment: Thank you for helping me Federico. But the code never gets into the function -> private DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> DbContextOptionsFactory(IServiceProvider provider) why is that?

Comment: @tunoandsuno Sorry about that, it appears that Entity Framework wants both `DbContextOptions` *and* `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>` to be registered in the Service Collection. Edited, now it should work. Also ensure that your `DbContext` implementation has a single constructor which [has `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>` as parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext).

Comment: @FedericoDipuma This is exactly the solution that am looking for, but am facing two issues  1. I want to do the same in my core API project.  if we write all the code in startup.cs file, then it will get triggered only once.  but what if i want the client determination and its corresponding injection to happen everytime a new request to API comes?  how do i handle that?  2.  am also facing same issue that the control is not hitting the DbContextOptionsFactory method.  I have two classes ClientEntities which inherts from DBContext and DBClient to which ClientEntities is injected.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma what class should i use in place of MyDbContext in above code?  i have also raised a separate question for this explaining my issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751031/dynamically-determine-the-connectionstring-of-dbcontext-in-asp-net-core

Comment: This is working great for me, but somehow once I use this method my ef core logging is turned off. I'm deep in a development cycle so this is inconvenient at best. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This way you can do it even more streamlined

```
services.AddScoped<ISqlConnectionContext, SqlConnectionContext>();
services.AddDbContext<SqlDbContext>((sp, builder) =>
    builder.UseSqlServer(sp.GetRequiredService<ISqlConnectionContext>().GetConnectionString()));
```

The `SqlConnectionContext` can now be implemented in any way you want.
For example using the `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: looks like services.Replace from accepted answer does not exist anymore in .net core 3.1, and this one worked for me.